# To delete entries from guava cache based on values at repeated time interval

Tags: spring-boot, guava

I am trying to remove keys which are having -1 as value from guava cache once in a day. Please suggest me on any methods in guava cache which are helpful to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know keys, the only way to remove entries is to iterate over whole cache, for example using `Cache#asMap()` view and `Map#removeIf(Predicate)`:

```
Cache<String, Integer> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .build();
cache.putAll(ImmutableMap.of(
        "one", 1,
        "two", 2,
        "something", -1,
        "-", -1,
        "forty-two", 42
));
System.out.println("Before: " + cache.asMap());
System.out.println(cache.getIfPresent("something"));

cache.asMap().entrySet().removeIf(e -> e.getValue().equals(-1));

System.out.println("After: " + cache.asMap());
System.out.println(cache.getIfPresent("something"));
```

outputs:

```
Before: {something=-1, two=2, -=-1, one=1, forty-two=42}
-1
After: {two=2, one=1, forty-two=42}
null
```